# Usage of OAuth2.0 Consumer Secret Keys

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, google-oauth

In OAuth1.0a the following process exists

Signatures play a good role to verify request from client and server.

1. Request Token

   Consumer Secret is used to create signatures.
2. Authorization Process
3. Exchanging temporary oauth token for permanent oauth token

   Can anyone explain what are the processes that exist in OAuth2.0 and what is the use of Consumer secret key?

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/topic/com.ibm.tivoli.fim.doc_6.2.2/config/concept/OAuth20Workflow.html) explains the workflow in OAuth 2.0 very clearly. Do go through it.

In Authorization code flow - 
1. Your app calls the OAuth provider, that opens a authorization window where the user keys in his credentials.
2. When the user grants access, the user's browser receives an authorization code. This authorization code would be passed to your client server.
3. Now, while exchanging this authorization code for an access token - the client passes the code along with the client_secret and client_ID.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's gives some clarity. But the Google URL gives clear picture of OAuth2.0

Comment: You're welcome. Google's OAuth documentation is really good, but I'd advice to read the RFC first if you have enough time.